# How to get a column to take up the rest of the horizontal space in a webpage

Tags: css, flexbox

I have some elements in a container X which are fixed-width, and I would like to create a column Y using CSS to take up the rest of the width if there is at least some min-width available, or move it below container X otherwise.

I've tried to use flexbox, but don't really understand it, and the example below pushes the `div.description` down below `div.interactive` if the text doesn't fit... I just want it to be pushed down if the available width isn't 200px or more.

How can I do this with flexbox?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Position demo</title>
<style type='text/css'>
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800);
 body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
 div.all {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
 }
 div.interactive {
  border: 1px solid red;
        flex-grow: 0;
 }
 div.description {
     flex-grow: 2;
        min-width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
 }
 div.canvas_holder {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 300;
 }
 div.canvas_title {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="all">
    <div class="interactive column">
 <div>
  <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
  <canvas id="canvas1" height="300" width="300" ></canvas>
  <div class="canvas_title"> canvas 1 </div>
  </div>

  <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
  <canvas id="canvas2" height="300" width="300" ></canvas>
  <div class="canvas_title"> canvas 2 </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="panel1">
 stuff goes here
 </div>
 </div> <!-- end of class=interactive -->
 
 <div class="description column">
 <p>Blah!</p>
 <p>asdfoijsafdoija asdfopsd fasdfo oopso bingo bango</p>
 </div> <!-- end of class-description -->

 </div> <!-- end of class=all -->
</body>
</html>
```

---

A longer example, trying to use [Temani Afif's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57385290/44330)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Position demo</title>
<style type='text/css'>
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800);
 body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
 div.all {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
 }
 div.interactive {
  border: 1px solid red;
        flex-grow: 0;
 }
 div.description {
     flex-grow: 2;
        flex-basis: 250px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
 }
 div.canvas_holder {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 300;
 }
 div.canvas_title {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="all">
    <div class="interactive column">
 <div>
  <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
  <canvas id="canvas1" height="300" width="300" ></canvas>
  <div class="canvas_title"> canvas 1 </div>
  </div>

  <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
  <canvas id="canvas2" height="300" width="300" ></canvas>
  <div class="canvas_title"> canvas 2 </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="panel1">
 stuff goes here
 </div>
 </div> <!-- end of class=interactive -->
 
 <div class="description column">
 <p>Blah!</p>
 <p>asdfoijsafdoija asdfopsd fasdfo oopso bingo bango.
    Twas brillig, and the slithy toves did gyre and gimble in the wabe.
    All mimsy were the borogoves and the momeraths outgrabe.
    </p>
 </div> <!-- end of class-description -->

 </div> <!-- end of class=all -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `flex-basis:0` to achieve what you want:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.all {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

div.interactive {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

div.description {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-basis: 0;
  min-width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
}

div.canvas_holder {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 300;
}

div.canvas_title {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="interactive column">
    <div>
      <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
        <canvas id="canvas1" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
        <div class="canvas_title"> canvas 1 </div>
      </div>

      <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
        <canvas id="canvas2" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
        <div class="canvas_title"> canvas 2 </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel1">
      stuff goes here
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of class=interactive -->

  <div class="description column">
    <p>Blah!</p>
    <p>asdfoijsafdoija asdfopsd fasdfo oopso bingo bango</p>
  </div>
  <!-- end of class-description -->

</div>
<!-- end of class=all -->
```

Or use `200px` inside `flex-basis`

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.all {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

div.interactive {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

div.description {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  min-width: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
}

div.canvas_holder {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 300;
}

div.canvas_title {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="interactive column">
    <div>
      <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
        <canvas id="canvas1" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
        <div class="canvas_title"> canvas 1 </div>
      </div>

      <div class="canvas_holder canvas_wide">
        <canvas id="canvas2" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
        <div class="canvas_title"> canvas 2 </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel1">
      stuff goes here
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of class=interactive -->

  <div class="description column">
    <p>Blah!</p>
    <p>asdfoijsafdoija asdfopsd fasdfo oopso bingo bango</p>
  </div>
  <!-- end of class-description -->

</div>
<!-- end of class=all -->
```

Comment: @JasonS it's all about `flex-basis` that set the initial size and by default it's equal to `auto` which means the size of its content and that size is the size of the element wilthout line break. So if there is not enough space to hold that size you will have a wrapping since you used `flex-wrap:wrap`. By changing flex-basis we can control the initial size.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't work if the content is longer though. (see 2nd example) What is pushing the content not to wrap?

Comment: @JasonS also notice the use of min-width:0 in my second exmple which is mandatory in some case, because a flex item has a min-width equal to auto and may also create issue like flex-basis:auto ... Will add those details to the answer